# Can't install Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8

I have a desktop running Windows 8 with the following specifications:

• Core Duo 3.2ghz processor
• 4GB RAM
• 500GB hard drive

Every time I try to install Ubuntu I get the following error:

```
Busybox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-ubuntu4) built in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built on commands
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Please keep it simple. I'm no programmer. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your SATA controller type from IDE to AHCI through BIOS settings.

Else, you can try to disconnect all unnecessary USB devices when booting from USB and during the installation.

Answer (score 2):

if disconnecting unnecessary USB devices doesn't fix the problem, then you probably have a damaged disc, be it from a scratch or a burning error.

assuming that the disc is scratched, and not too badly, try wiping it off with a polishing cloth. when i don't have one handy, i just use a clean t-shirt.

otherwise, you'll have to burn the ISO file to a new disc.

i had the same problem with a 10.04 disc a while back, burned the image to a new disc, and it worked fine.